# return dummy interface instance?

Tags: java

I have example code from a third party related to some API. It doesn't run because of an unhandled exception in a return statement.

The problem: The return type is an interface whose instances are always created with complicated factories (assume I do not have access to these). Thus even if I handle the exception in the stupid do-nothing way, I still can't return a valid dummy object.

```
public FunnyInterface calculateSomething()
{
   return builder.someFunnyInterface(); // throws Exception
}
```

To get this code to run, is there anything I can do not involving:

- modifying the code along the route where `calculateSomething()` is called,
- finding a builder in the API that won't throw an Exception, or
- manually writing a dummy class implementing the interface

?

Comment: Your problem is not how to deal with the exception, it is what is causing the exception.  Prevent the exception by not causing the exception.

Comment: If there is no declaration of a checked exception in the method you are calling, then something very unexpected is happening to be throwing some runtime exception. Check your initialisation of stuff.

Comment: Depending on who threw the exception and why, their may be nothing you can do, or the fix could be one line of code. You need to share the exception being thrown, and try to give a Minimal complete, verifiable example.

Comment: You all were right. The code is missing "throws ..." declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wrote that you can't call the builder, I guess that you are not interested in the value of type `FunnyInterface`, so just return `null`.

```
public FunnyInterface calculateSomething() {
    try {
        return builder.someFunnyInterface(); // throws Exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or just

```
public FunnyInterface calculateSomething() {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Forgot that java also has nulls! I'm used to C++.

Comment: You are lucky with Java, if you had to do that with Swift or Kotlin, it would have been tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a simple rethrow with wrapped in a RuntimeException so you don't need to declare a checked exception:

```
// Dummy mockup interface + function
public static interface FunnyInterface {}
public static FunnyInterface builder_someFunnyInterface() throws Exception { return null; }

public FunnyInterface calculateSomething() {
    try {
        return builder_someFunnyInterface(); // throws Exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I would not return null. If you don't have a meaningful way to handle the error, propagate it upwards to a level that does have a meaningful way to handle the error. If you really do want to return null/empty, then use Optional, otherwise throwing an unchecked RuntimeException is preferable.